# Why is SetAuthCookie not called directly in Membership.ValidateUser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I am currently implementing a custom membership provider in ASP.NET MVC3 and have been looking at examples of different sample implementations. I have noticed that `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` never seems to be called from the `ValidateUser` method in the provider. It always seems to be called in the function which calls `ValidateUser` if `ValidateUser` returns true. This is usually some form of authentication helper.

What I don't understand is that `SetAuthCookie()` seems to be called once `ValidateUser` returns true. So my question is why not just integrate it directly?

Comment: I think that would be a side effect of the method. Otherwise this method would be named `ValidateUserAndSetAuthCookie()`.

Comment: I agree with Alexander's comment and in addition you assuming that ValidateUser would always be used for Forms Authentication and cookies. It could be used for other types of authentication that does not require setting cookies.

Comment: MembershipProvider is an abstract class. In the examples that I have come across each implementation calls `SetAuthCookie()` outside of the  method by a helper each and every time. Your comment @AlexanderS. makes good sense, but I suppose what I would be interested in knowing is if there is a reason to **not** integrate it in a site which always uses cookies for authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done because of separation of concerns i guess.

The membership providers responsibility is just to validate whether a given username/password pair is valid or not.

The `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` methods task is to transform that information (the user has authenticated itself successfully) into a serializable format (cookie or url parameter) so that it survives the next HTTP request.

You could replace both implementations independent of each other, storing the authentication information in a cookie is just the most common way on the asp.net platform.